# Construct integer from little-endian values in C

Tags: c, char, type-conversion

I have several variables in C:

- `char* data` pointer to data (always in LE)
- `int dataStart` - `data` offset from which my integer starts
- `int dataLength` - number of bytes with integer data (`0<=dataLength<=8`)
- `int sign` - either `1` for positive numbers or `-1` for negative values

How can I convert it to `__int64` (or do I need something else?) value in C?

I know that integers are limited to `2^63−1`.

Comment: Make an attempt.  When you get stuck, come back with a **specific** question in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: Are the characters raw bytes that should be interpreted numerically, or are they strings? IOW, would the number `1234` correspond to bytes `08 D2`, `D2 08`, or `49 50 51 52`? And having established that, what else is stopping you from converting to the form you need?

Answer (score -1):

```
int64_t makeint(const char *buff, size_t offset, size_t offsetinint, size_t len, int minus)
{
    union
    {
        int64_t i64;
        uint8_t u8[8]
    }d64;

    offsetinint = offsetinint & 7;
    memset(&d64, 0, sizeof(d64));

    memcpy(&d64.u8[offsetinint], len > (8 - offsetinint) ? (8 - offsetinint) : len, buff + offset);
    d64.i64 *= -1 * !!minus;
    return d64.i64;
}
```